# comparing dates with linq ambiguous

Tags: linq, date

I'm trying to compare a property to a date with linq and I'm getting an error 'Pages_ColumnDropdown_Default' is ambiguous.  I'm using asp.net 4.0.  Here is the code

```
Private Class SomeData
    Public Property El0 As Integer
    Public Property El1 As String
    Public Property El2 As String
    Public Property El3 As String
    Public Property eDate As DateTime
End Class

Dim oS As New List(Of SomeData)
    Dim o As New SomeData

    With o
        .El0 = 1
        .El1 = "Element 1 - Row 1"
        .El2 = "Element 2 - Row 2"
        .El3 = "Element 2 - Row 3"
        .eDate = CDate("2/1/2014")
        oS.Add(o)
    End With

    o = New SomeData
    With o
        .El0 = 2
        .El1 = "Element 1 - Row 1"
        .El2 = "Element 2 - Row 2"
        .El3 = "Element 2 - Row 3"
        .eDate = CDate("12/1/2013")
        oS.Add(o)
    End With

    o = New SomeData
    With o
        .El0 = 3
        .El1 = "Element 1 - Row 1"
        .El2 = "Element 2 - Row 2"
        .El3 = "Element 2 - Row 3"
        .eDate = CDate("1/1/2014")
        oS.Add(o)
    End With

    Dim mm As String = Date.Today.ToString
    Dim mList = From w In oS
              Where w.eDate = CDate("1/14/2014")
              Select w
```

I also tried using mm.  Anyway.. seems I've done this quite a few times before but never run into this error.  I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction

**This bit added in response to suggestions**
I've changed the code a bit to reflect what was suggested.  By putting this

```
Dim cultureinfo As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us")
    Dim mm As String = Now.ToShortDateString
    Dim mList = From w In oS
              Where w.eDate = DateTime.Parse("12/1/2014", cultureinfo)
              Select w
```

the linq statement runs and gives no error.  However, if I try to make it more dynamic and put in
mm for the date of "12/1/2014", the error comes back.  So the changed code that does not work comes back as

```
Dim cultureinfo As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us")
    Dim mm As String = Now.ToShortDateString
    Dim mList = From w In oS
              Where w.eDate = DateTime.Parse(mm, cultureinfo)
              Select w
```

when I look to see what DateTime.Parse(mm,cultureinfo) is getting rendered as, here is the result

```
? DateTime.Parse(mm, cultureinfo)
#1/16/2014#
```

and here is what it looks like when hard coded

```
? DateTime.Parse("1/16/2014", cultureinfo)
#1/16/2014#
```

the two look identical to me.. so again.. i'm missing something.  Hope someone can inlighten me.
Thanks
shannon

Comment: What on earth is "Pages_ColumnDropdown_Default"? This must be something from your code but its not obvious what so trying to work out why it is ambiguous is tricky... For a start it might help to find out what line it happens on...

Comment: "Pages_ColumnDropdown_Default" is the name of the webform page that the code sits on.  The error comes in the linq statement.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like conversion of the dates is not aware of the culture so doesn't know whether "12/1/2013" is 12th January (e.g. if the culture is say en-gb) or 1st December (e.g. if the culture is en-us).

You could explicitly set the culture when parsing the date strings:

```
Dim cultureinfo  As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us")

... later in your code ...
.eDate = DateTime.Parse("12/1/2013",cultureinfo)
```

Comment: allergy.. if you could please look in the edited post and comment again.. that would be much apprecicated

Comment: Ok, looked at your edits. If you're confident that the `.eDate=DateTime.Parse("1/1/2014",cultureinfo)` assignment is working.  , then you know that `eDate` is a valid date, so you shouldn't need to convert `Today`.

Your LINQ query should be able to read:

`Dim mList = From w In oS Where w.eDate.Date = Date.Today Select w`

Comment: I appreciate your time.. Dim mList = From w In oS Where w.eDate = Date.Today Select w still give me the error.  I made a change to the value of third instance of Somedata so that the .eDate=cdate("1/16/2014") so that there should be a single row coming back if the linq is satisfied.  I also tried changing the datet value in each of the properties when assignin git to El3 to use the code .eDate = DateTime.Parse("2/1/2014", cultureinfo).  Same issue.

Comment: Note that I used `Where w.eDate.Date = Date.Today` - you've omitted the `.Date` part from `w.eDate.Date` in your reply.  It may not make much difference, but at least it means you explicitly asking for the date part of the DateTime object.

Comment: One other thing - what's the actual error message, inc. stack trace?  It may be that the dates are a total red herring if there is an actual error.

Comment: I tried the where w.eDate.Date=Date.today.  that does work.. as long as there is a match.  When there is no match, the error occurs.  I think this is the error that you are requesting.`A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: If you get the error when nothing matches, then you need to look further on in your code.  The error is nothing to do with the dates and it sounds like it is to do with something further on (e.g. code or components that are not expecting empty collections in `mlist`).

The error sounds more like a file access exception error, the sort you get when your app is not running elevated privileges etc.  but I can't see how that ties into occurring with non-matches in `mlist`.